# How "dojo.connect" be modified to call 2 functions with on-click event

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I want to call 2 functions on a click event.
I tried the below way but it didn't help, basically I would like to call **`get`** and **`refresh`** on click

```
dojo.connect(this.next, "onclick", "get");  
dojo.connect(this.next, "onclick", "refresh");
```

one way is to call a function which inturn calls get and refresh. But how do I achieve this....

Comment: what's var1 ? you mean dojo.connect ?

Comment: yes dojo.connect

Comment: Okey great check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use function that call both get and refresh
as below :

```
dojo.connect(this.next, "onclick", function(e) {
   get(e);
   refresh(e);
});
```

if you're using dojo >= 1.7 , you better use [dojo/on](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#dojo-on) for handling events,

your code would become : ( after importing `"dojo/on"` )

```
on(this.next, "click", function(e){
   get(e);
   refresh(e);
});
```